# Sending a JSON string with escape sequences within another JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net

Ok this question is a confusing one. I have a website which communicates with a .NET application through websockets. I send requests to the application using JSON strings. Now I have a string like given below,

```
var stringIwantTosend = "{
       \r\n\t\"webcam.codec\": \"WMV3\",
       \r\n\t\"webcam.width\": 640,
       \r\n\t\"webcam.height\": 480,
       \r\n\t\"webcam.fps\": 25,
       \r\n\t\"codec.level\": 3,
       \r\n\t\"codec.bitrate\": 1400,
       \r\n\t\"codec.rate_control\": \"VBR\",
       \r\n\t\"codec.quality\": 75,
       \r\n\t\"font.family\": \"Arial\",
       \r\n\t\"font.size\": 14,
       \r\n\t\"font.style\": [ \"Bold\", \"Italic\" ]\r\n
}"
```

I want send this string AS IT IS to the application. No matter how much I try it gets formatted!

This is what I use to create the JSON string,

```
var JSON = '{"request": "'+name+'",'+
            '"parameters":'+stringIwantTosend+','+
            '"pid": "'+pid+'"'+
            '}';
```

During this creation the string gets formatted and JsonConvert.SerializeObject thinks it is another JSON string to be serialized and thats not what I want!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: don't use string concatenation, if it is a valid json then simply use JObjet.Parse(stringIwantTosend);

Comment: So you are trying to embed a JSON string within another JSON string?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do.